# Generic operations on sequences

Tags: scala, collections, types, covariance

I am working on this simple project where I want to make a Genetic Algorithm to find near-optimal values for a certain fitness function. In short it looks something like this:

```
class Individual[T](val underlying: T, val fitnessFunc: T => Double) {
    lazy val fitness: Double = fitnessFunc(underlying)
    def update(x: T): Individual[T] = new Individual[T](x, fitnessFunc)
}

class Population[T](individuals: Seq[Individual[T]]) {
    def best: Individual[T] = individuals.tail.foldLeft(individuals.head)((b, a) => if(b.fitness > a.fitness) b else a) // not sure if this is the best way btw
}

trait GeneticAlgorithm[T] {
    def select(p: Population[T]): Individual[T]
    def crossover(i1: Individual[T], i2: Individual[T]): (Individual[T], Individual[T])
    def mutate(i: Individual[T]): Individual[T]
    def evolve(p: Population[T]): Population[T] {
        ...
    }
}
```

This way I can create an implementation of the `GeneticAlgorithm` specifically for a certain type `T`. I am now busy creating some implementations of selection, crossover and mutation strategies.

I am however running into problems when `T` is a sequence. For this type I want to have a mutation-strategy which is, for instance, just a random shuffle with a certain chance:

```
object Mutation {
    def shuffleVector(p: Double): Individual[Vector[_]] => Individual[Vector[_] = (i: Individual[Vector[_]) => {
        if (math.random < p) i.update(scala.util.Random.shuffle(i.underlying)) else i
    }
}
```

Apart from the fact that it is specific to Vector and not any Sequence, it compiles just fine. The reason I used existential types is that I do not care what type the Vector is of.

When I want to use it however, I run into problems. For instance when I want to optimize a Vector of ints:

```
val ga = new GeneticAlgorithm[Vector[Int]] {
    ...
    override def mutate(i: Individual[Vector[Int]]): Individual[Vector[Int]] = Mutation.shuffleVector(0.5)(i)
    ...
}
```

I get the error: `Expression of type Individual[Vector[_]] doesn't conform to expected type Individual[Vector[Int]]`.

Besides from some other things that can be fixed, what is the proper way to solve this? I suspect it has to do something with coveriancy, but not sure yet. Been busy learning the Scala ways... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, not that you asked, but ...

```
individuals.tail.foldLeft(individuals.head)((b, a) => if(b.fitness > a.fitness) b else a)
```

`something.tail.foldLeft(something.head)(f)` is equivalent to `something.reduce(f)`.

Moreover, your snippet is actually equivalent to `individuals.maxBy(_.fitness)`

Now, to answer your question, the solution is simple: just make your shuffle function generic:

```
def maybeShuffle[T](p: Double, xs: Seq[T]): Seq[T] = 
  if(math.random < p) scala.util.Random.shuffle(xs) else xs
```

Comment: Yes, that indeed is the most obvious solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This actually might be one of these cases where using the underscore as a shorthand for the existential type actually doesn't produce the obvious result.

```
Individual[Vector[_]]
```

gets translated to

```
Individual[Vector[T]] forSome {type T}
```

which is different from

```
Individual[Vector[T] forSome {type T}]
```

which is probably what you have in mind.

I think that if you change the signature of the method that error will disappear.